Using TEXTJOIN to display table values of numbers within certain criteria
This is a continuation of a previous question that was solved BUT I realised I had more criteria to fulfill.
In the previous post, I received formulas that can:
Retrieve the table value for the highest value
Retrieve the table value for a value within 0.02 of the highest value
As so:

But I've realised I also need to retrieve table values for numbers that are over 0.3, as in below:

If possible can both these criteria be combined into one formula?
I have tried the formula on the example below:
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(C14:H14,MAX(C15:H15)-C15:H15<=0.02),FILTER(C14:H14,MAX(C15:H15)-C15:H15<=0.3))

But have no idea why the results are as shown. Have played around with it, can't get it to make sense, especially coming back with the 2 in the 0,0,1,2 cell.

within your text you write "that are over 0.3" but your formula uses "<=0.3" ... Please show us your expected output.

Hi Ike, yah, the formula is wrong, but I couldn't get the formula to work as I wanted with what I thought was correct so was fiddling about with < and > and values

As said: show us the expected result - then it is easier to understand what you want to achieve

Criteria I'm after is to show the GOALS figure for values that are:
Highest
Values within 0.02 of the highest
Anything over 0.30
and not to error if there's only 1 value over 0.3

What I  mean by "expected result" is that you put sample data in your question and then the expected result for these data - obviously you will have to create the expected result for the sample data manually.

Try this one:
=LET(header,B1:G1,
    data,B2:G5,
    BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,
        TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,
            FILTER(header,(r>0.3)+(MAX(r)-r<=0.02))
            )
        )
    )
)


Row 5 is an edge example:

0.31 is the max value of the row (and > 0.3)
0.29 is <= 0,02 diff from 0.31


Absolutely brilliant, works a treat! Thank-you so much!! I will remember you when the millions come rolling in!!!!

Would be great if you mark it as an answer: What should I do when someone answers my question?

I was wondering how t do that - figured it out, thanks again!

As Ike asked, I'm not sure about the condition, but here's way using Name Manager.

For OR conditions, we can use + between conditions
In Name Manager add goals_if with formula

=LAMBDA(g,v, LET(include, (v > 0.3) + (MAX(v) - v <= 0.02), 
TEXTJOIN(", ", , TOROW(IF(include, g, NA()), 2), )))

Then use where the results are needed:
=goals_if($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2)

=goals_if($B$1:$G$1,B3:G3)


with multiple rows:
=LET(data, B1:G5, BYROW(DROP(data, 1), LAMBDA(row_, goals_if(TAKE(data, 1), row_))))



Thanks, looks understandable, I will try this out a bit later after work!

Ah, not so understandable but could probably work it out. However, not sure this will work as I have 84 of these Home/Away boxes in a sheet - can this work with multiple incidences?

I'm sorry, I'm try to improve next time. I wanted to have a formula that could be applied in different sheets with different ranges for goals and home/away rows (using the same condition.)  Logic is basically the same as Ike's, but using TOROW instead of FILTER. I added an example with multiple rows.
